# Mac - Keyboard shortcut for cycling through tabs in Xcode, Terminal, Safari, Firefox

Tags: xcode, macos, tabs, terminal

I'm running Xcode 4.4 on Mountain Lion.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for cycling through open tabs in a window?

I know that <kbd>COMMAND</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> cycles through the Xcode windows, but I want to cycle through tabs.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for this?

Comment: Do `COMMAND-{` and `COMMAND-}` work?  I don't have a Mac handy to test...

Comment: Yes, thanks! Feel free to put this in an answer, and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Nice!  That works for Terminal, Safari, Firefox, and probably others, too... We should probably edit the question title.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This works for Terminal, Xcode, Safari, Firefox, and probably many others:

Previous Tab: <kbd>COMMAND</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd>

Next Tab: <kbd>COMMAND</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd>

It's easy to remember:

- the braces point left and right (towards the tabs they activate)
- the keys are positioned conveniently next to each other on the keyboard.

Comment: Note that these can be configured in Xcode's preferences window. Look for Select Next Tab and Select Previous Tab (or just type the word 'tab' in the search bar on the Key Bindings page.)

Comment: As of Xcode 11.2.1, your answer is not valid. This doesn't work.
Please update your answer to `ctrl` + `tab` / `ctrl` + `shift` +`tab` and `command` + `shift` + `{` / `command` + `shift` + `}` .

Comment: @chandil03 - Isn't that what I have? You can't type a `{` or `}` character without hitting shift.

Comment: Ohh, sorry missed it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative way to cycle tabs across Mac apps: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>

Add <kbd>shift</kbd> to toggle direction.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Model.m to AttachmentFile.swift tab use: `ctrl` + `tab` ; `ctrl` + `shift` + `tab` to go backwards

Model.m to Entitlement.swift mini tab use: `cmd` + `shift` + `{` or `}`

To other window of Xcode use: `cmd` + `~`

Answer (score 0):

Named shortcuts do not activate *recent* tabs, but help *cycle through* tabs in either direction. Firefox has a nice feature with which tabs used are available as a **stack** and can be accessed in the same manner the OS allows switching between recently used applications (in FF it's `Ctrl+Tab` on macOS).